# How to open View Controller in Table View with Button by using Objc in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, uiviewcontroller

Stackoverflow

I know how to make a button in the table view cells with website links, rate, mail, and many things. However, How could I open the view controller with the `instantiateViewController` in the `@Objc` func's statements?

For example.

Create a new Table View Cell folder called `FeedBackButtonsTableViewCell`

```
class FeedBackButtonsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ButtonCells: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Let create a new view controller folder called

```
class FeedbackViewController: UIViewController {


       @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

          self.navigationItem.title = "Feedback"
    }

}
```

add the extension to calling the view controller to `UITableViewDataSource` and  `UITableViewDelegate` and create a obj func statements inside of the second `FeedbackViewController` with  `UITableViewDataSource` and  `UITableViewDelegate` under the cells.

```
extension FeedbackViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

     if indexPath.row == 1 {

            buttonCell = TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonCells") as? FeedBackButtonsTableViewCell

             buttonCell?.ButtonCells.addTarget(self,action: #selector(LearnMore),for: .touchUpInside)

             buttonCell?.ButtonCells.tag = indexPath.row

             return buttonCell!

        }

  @objc func LearnMore() {

    // How could I write to open the view controller with UIButton in the Table View Cells?

  }
}
```

Thank you for bring a kind of help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution could be to use procol.

```swift
protocol CellActionDelegate{
    func didButtonTapped(index: Int)
}
```

Now confirm the protocol in `FeedbackViewController`. Take `index` and `actionDelegate` properties in your UITableViewCell subclass.

```swift
class FeedBackButtonsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

    var actionDelegate: CellActionDelegate?
    var index: Int?

    .....



    // Take Action of UIButton here

    @IBAction func more(_ sender: Any) {
      if let delegate = self.actionDelegate{

        delegate.didButtonTapped(index!)
      }
    }


}
```

Now in your `FeedbackViewController` set actionDelegate & Corresponding index in

```swift
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
```

you can open anotherView controller from `func didButtonTapped(index: Int)` definition  .

```swift
extension FeedbackViewController:CellActionDelegate{
 func didButtonTapped(index: Int) {
        let storybord = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let controller = storybord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnotherControllerIdentfier") as? AnotherViewController else{
            fatalError("Could not finc another view controller")
        }
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s getting error says

“Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction”

When I add the IBAction.

And how could I add instantiateViewController for open the view controller?

Comment: @IBAction method you need to take as action i.e ctrl+drag from UIButton (From storyboard cell ) to  FeedBackButtonsTableViewCell

Comment: Seem, It's almost there! However, I got crashed. :( You might check this debug? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QLrGqjkTLCjs51A_zgZSwI7yYWXjpEZn8NQmX-gGjl4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: LearnMoreCells = TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LearnMore") as? LearnMoreTableViewCell
                                          
   LearnMoreCells?.ButtonCells.addTarget(self,action: #selector(didButtonTapped),for: .touchUpInside)
   LearnMoreCells?.ButtonCells.tag = indexPath.row
                                  
   return LearnMoreCells!

Comment: You should not add gesture on UIButton instead you should set actionDelegate like this .
```LearnMoreCells.actionDelegate = self``` .
If you are not using Protocol & actionDelegate in UITableViewCell then Gesture will be helpful but UIButton by default have tapped gesture in that case error will occurred.

Comment: Btw: this delegate.didButtonTapped(index!) showed the error says request to add index: delegate.didButtonTapped(index: index!)... When I add  LearnMoreCells.actionDelegate = self and crashed and return to that one.

Comment: dont use this call ```LearnMoreCells?.ButtonCells.addTarget(self,action: #selector(didButtonTapped),for: .touchUpInside) ```

Comment: When I removed that LearnMoreCells?.ButtonCells.addTarget(self,action: #selector(didButtonTapped),for: .touchUpInside), it's still crash and red error says: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in this delegate.didButtonTapped(index: index!).

Comment: Like the way you set actionDelegate set index as well 
```LearnMoreCells.actionDelegate = self
  LearnMoreCells.index = indexPath.row``` now It won't crash

Comment: Finally, Thank you so much for kind help!!!! It's solved the problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @objc func LearnMore() {

        let viewController = FeedbackDetailsViewController()// creation of viewController object differs depends on how you fetch the UI, means either you are using storyboard or xib or directly making ui in code.
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

      }
```

Comment: That's not work. :( I tried replace this FeedbackDetailsViewController  to LearnMoreTableViewController which it is that view controller has written whole of the code, not storyboard.